Get type of Entity Field along with length if its string and values if its enum
public static void main(Args _args)
{

    var entityNames = Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.MetadataSupport::GetDataEntityViewNames();
    var enumerator = entityNames.GetEnumerator();

    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var EntityName = enumerator.Current;
        Info(strFmt("The Entity Name is %1",EntityName));

        var DataEntity = Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.MetadataSupport::GetDataEntityView(enumerator.Current);
        var dataEntityFields = DataEntity.Fields;
        var fieldsEnumerator = dataEntityFields.GetEnumerator();

        while (fieldsEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var FieldName = fieldsEnumerator.Current.ToString();
            Info(strFmt("The First Field Name is %1 : Field Type is %2",FieldName, typeOf(FieldName)));
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    
}

While iterating over the Data Entities, I want the fieldType of each field. In case of string I want the string size and in case of Enum I want the enum name so that I can get the enum values.
SysDict works for table but it's not working for data entities.
Appreciate any tips.

For data entities you can use DictDataEntity class.
Below is the solution implemented based on your question:
public class Test_Class
{
    public static void main(Args _args)
    {
        DictDataEntity      entity;
        DictDataEntityField deFld;
        var                 entityNames = Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.MetadataSupport::GetDataEntityViewNames();
        var                 enumerator  = entityNames.GetEnumerator();
        
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var currEntityName = enumerator.Current;

            entity          = new DictDataEntity(tableName2Id(currEntityName));

            Info(strFmt("The Entity Name is %1", currEntityName));

            int fldcnt = 1;
            while (fldCnt <= entity.fieldCnt())
            {
                deFld = new DictDataEntityField(entity.id(), entity.fieldCnt2Id(fldCnt));

                if (deFld && !deFld.isSystem())
                {
                    Info(strFmt("Field Name is %1 : Field Type is %2%3", deFld.name(), deFld.baseType(), Test_Class::getFieldProperty(deFld)));
                }
                fldCnt++;
            }

            break;
        }
    
    }

    public static str getFieldProperty(DictDataEntityField _field)
    {
        str label = "";

        switch (_field.baseType())
        {
            case Types::Enum:
                label += ": Enum Name is ";
                label += enumId2Name(_field.enumId());
                break;
            case Types::String:
                label += ": String length is ";
                label += int2Str(_field.stringLen());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return label;
    }
}

